# Video Texture Not Showing On Cube

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Hey guys im trying to figure out why my `Cube` isnt showing the video texture that I added... It shows a image, which is pretty simple to implement.. But when trying to map a video texture its not doing it...

```js
video = document.createElement('video');
video.width = 320;
video.height = 240;
video.autoplay = true;
video.src = "my video.....";

var videoTexture = new THREE.Texture( video );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
 map:texture, map: videoTexture} );

// render update....
 if( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ){ videoTexture.needsUpdate = true; }
```

but still its not showing my video on the cubes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 maps defined there:

```
map:texture, map: videoTexture
```

Maybe the first one is overriding the second one.